# HTML Code failing in github. Failing in pages and build development

Tags: html, github

I am receiving the following error after I git add [my files] and git push [my files] to github.

Error: fatal: No url found for submodule path 'odin-recipes' in .gitmodules
Error: The process '/usr/bin/git' failed with exit code 128

While in my proper working directory, git status and git log return that everything is fine.

I simply added and commited my code and the url is not found i'm not sure why.